# Why are the conditions for an implicitly-defined move constructor/assignment operator different than for copy operations?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, language-design, assignment-operator

Why does C++ compiler have more restriction on automatically generated move constructors than on automatically generated copy constructor or assignment operator ?

Automatically generated move constructors are generated only if user has defined nothing (i.e: constructor, copy, assignment, destructor..)

Copy constructor or assignment operator are generated only if user has not defined respectively copy constructor or assignment operator.

I wonder why the difference.

Comment: From a mere conceptual viewpoint (beware, no technical explanation), the two are not equal, e.g. every copyable object is movable but not the other way around. Moving is rather a special case of copying applicable in certain situations. So it makes sense that their autogeneration behaviour is somehow skewed. But I leave it to someone else to translate that into technical standardese with proper examples. Other than than good question, of course.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe backwards compatibility plays a big part here. If the user defines any of the "Rule of three" functions (copy ctor, copy assignment op, dtor), it can be assumed the class does some internal resource management. Implicitly defining a move constructor could suddenly make the class invalid when compiled under C++11.

Consider this example:

```
class Res
{
  int *data;

public:
  Res() : data(new int) {}

  Res(const Res &arg) : data(new int(*arg.data)) {}

  ~Res() { delete data; }
};
```

Now if a default move constructor was generated for this class, its invocation would lead to a double deletion of `data`.

As for the move assignment operator preventing default move constructor definitions: if the move assignment operator does something other than default one, it would most likely be wrong to use the default move constructor. That's just the "Rule of three"/"Rule of five" in effect.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, this is because of downward compatibility. Consider classes written in C++ (before C++11) and what would happen if C++11 would start to automatically generate move-ctors in parallel to existing copy-ctors or generally any other ctor. It would easily break existing code, by-passing the copy-ctor the author of that class wrote. Hence, the rules for generating a move-ctor where crafted to only apply to "safe" cases.

Here's *the* article from Dave Abrahams about [why implicit move must go](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/10/implicit-move-must-go/), which eventually led to the current rules of C++11.

And this is an example how it would fail:

```
// NOTE: This example assumes an implicitly generated move-ctor

class X
{
private:    
    std::vector<int> v;

public:
    // invariant: v.size() == 5
    X() : v(5) {}

    ~X()
    {
        std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<X> y;

    // and here is where it would fail:
    // X() is an rvalue: copied in C++03, moved in C++0x
    // the classes' invariant breaks and the dtor will illegally access v[0].
    y.push_back(X());
}
```

Answer (score 9):

When C++ was created, it was decided that default constructor, copy-constructor, assignment-operator and destructor would be generated automatically (unless provided). Why ? Because C++ compilers should be able to compile (most) C code with identical semantics, and that's how `struct` work in C.

However, it was later noticed that whenever a user writes a custom destructor, she probably needs to write a custom copy-constructor/assignment-operator too; this is known as the [Rule of Big Three](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RuleOfTheBigThree). With hindsight, we can see that it could have been specified that the generated copy-constructor/assignment-operator/destructor would have only been generated if none of the 3 were user-provided, and it would have helped catch a lot of bugs... and still retain backward compatibility with C.

Therefore, as C++11 came around, it was decided that this time things would be done right: the new move-constructor and move-assignment-operator would only be generated automatically if it was clear that the user was not doing anything "special" with the class. Anything "special" being defined as redefining move/copy/destruction behavior.

To help with the case were people would be doing something special but still wanted "automatically generated" special methods, the `= default` sugar-coating was added as well.

Unfortunately, for backward compatibility reasons, the C++ committee could not go back in time and change the rules of automatic generation for copy; <strike>I wish they had deprecated it to pave the way for the next version of the Standard, but I doubt they will.</strike> it is however deprecated (see §12.8/7 for the copy constructor for example, courtesy of @Nevin).

Comment: I've never heard it called the "Rule of Big Three"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Added the link :)

Comment: The old copy constructor/assignment operator rules *are* deprecated in C++11.  Take a look at n3485 12.8p7 and 12.8p18.  To quote 12.8p7: "If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4). The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor." (12.8p18 is the same language for the copy assignment operator.)

Comment: @Nevin: Thanks for the quote! I had missed it somehow. I'll include it in the answer :)